# sanitize string for use in href with PHP GET

Tags: php, javascript, regex, get, href

I am trying to add a user-defined string to information passed to a third party via href.  So I have something that will look like

```
<a href="http://thirdparty.com/?data_set=USERSTRING" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

USERSTRING is known when the page loads so it could be put in the href by php when the page loads, or I can dynamically add it with javascript.

What I don't know is what I need to do to escape any special characters so that the link works and can be read on the other end - USERSTRING could be something really annoying like: [He said, "90% isn't good enough?"]  The data is only used in an auto-generated file name so it doesn't need to be preserved 100%, but I'm trying to avoid gratuitous ugliness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)() function provides exactly what you are looking for, ie:

```
<a href="http://thirdparty.com/?data_set=<?php echo urlencode('USERSTRING'); ?>" target="_blank">Link Text</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) it.  If the variant of urlencode you end up using doesn't encode '&', '#', '"', and angle brackets as it should then you'll need to HTML encode it too.

Comment: i believe that if the value passed to a single GET argument contains one of the special chars you mention that it would be encoded appropriately by urlencode(). where those chars appear elsewhere in a URL they should be encoded via htmlentities(). this might happen when there are more than one GET arg separated via &, or when URL contains a target anchor at the end after #

Comment: @nathan, Agreed.  I mention it only because framework-specific functions that claim to do the same job might be more lax.  For example, `htmlentities` encodes quotes so can be used for attribute value content, but not all seemingly-equivalent functions do so.